# Cannot find the Block file

Tags: blocks, phtml

When templates hints are turned ON , it is shown that

**Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor**

is responsible for

> /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

when I browsed to the loaction

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart

There is Sidebar.php

Not Sidebar/Interceptor.php, which is expected from the block name conventions followed by magento.

Where can I find the file?

Also In which layout file the `minicart.phtml` file is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes that end with `Interceptor`, `Proxy` and `Factory` (but not all of them) may be found in `generated/code` folder.
They all look very similar.
But please don't change them because they get regenerated.

You will see that all `Interceptor` classes have the following characteristics:

They extend a class with the same as the current class except there is a missing "interceptor" at the end.
All methods in the interceptor look like this:

```
public function methodNameHere(parameters here)
{
    $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'methodNameHere');
    if (!$pluginInfo) {
        return parent::methodNameHere(parameters here);
    } else {
        return $this->___callPlugins('methodNameHere', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
    }
}
```

This is a method to change the behavior of a function without changing the function itself.
Read more about [code generation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html) and [plugins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: That's most satisfying answer. Hats off